# Replace character at certain location within string

Tags: r, string, character

Given a certain string, e.g., `s = "tesX123"`, how can I replace a certain character at a certain location?

In this example, the character at position `4` should be changed to `"t"`.

Does a method exist in the style of `setChar(s, 4, "t")` which would result in `test123`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try `substr()`

```
substr(s, 4, 4) <- "t"
> s
#[1] "test123"
```

Answer (score 10):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("(.{3}).", "\\1t", s)
#[1] "test123"
```