# Insert a string at a specific index of a string without overriding any of either string in R

Tags: r, regex

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596928/replace-character-at-certain-location-within-string-in-r) question, but without overriding any of the existing string

E.g.

```
string <- "ABC123"
part_of_string <- "-"

# Desired output (example)
# [1] "ABC-123"
```

Comment: You can adapt an answer from the question you linked to do this:  `sub("(.{3})", "\\1-", "ABC123")`

Comment: @H1 it works, thanks. Out of curiosity, why does the second argument to `sub()` have `\\1` ? (it seems unnecessary), but I'm probably missing why it's necessary (or perhaps there's more sophisticated things can be done with it)

Comment: Leave it out and you will see what it is doing :-)

Comment: @G5W ah yes, it is a reference to the regex capture grouping, so when `sub()` takes it out, it reinserts it, but with this time with the new string attached

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `gsub`:

```
index=3
gsub( paste( '(.{', index, '})(.*)', sep = "" ),
      paste( '\\1', part_of_string, '\\2', sep = ""),
      string 
      )
```