# How to replace part of a string by position

Tags: r

I have a string that looks like this:

```
Jun:2020,XXX/XXX|May:2020,035/XXX|Apr:2020,040/XXX|
```

I want to replace only the first occurrence of XXX which starts at position 10 with 000.

Comment: Maybe this question could help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596928/replace-character-at-certain-location-within-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is `sub`, if you're not certain that the first XXX will always start at position 10:

```
sub("XXX", "000", "Jun:2020,XXX/XXX|May:2020,035/XXX|Apr:2020,040/XXX|")
# [1] "Jun:2020,000/XXX|May:2020,035/XXX|Apr:2020,040/XXX|"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact start and stop position, then `substr` can do the job as in

```
String <- "123456789"
substr(String, start = 4, stop = 6) <- "XXX"
print(String)
```

which will replace from position 4 to 6 and result in

```
> print(String)
[1] "123XXX789"
```

The same goes for

```
str <- "Jun:2020,XXX/XXX|May:2020,035/XXX|Apr:2020,040/XXX|"
substr(str, 10, 12) <- "000"
str
```